# CoreData - many-to-many relationship with priorities

Tags: ios, mysql, database, sqlite, core-data

I have conceptual question about DB schema. I have 2 entities: `Team` and `Member`.

1.`Member` can belong to many `Teams`,

2.`Team` can have many `Members`.

So it's many-to-many relationship and I've implemented it successfully. Now the client wants to have ordered `Members` within a `Team`. So `Member` can have priority in one team different than in the other.

How properly implemented DB schema should look like? I considering about 2 options:

- with minimum work effort
- the proper solution

Any hints are more than welcome. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should create a new table, eg `MemberSort`, which has `memberId`, `teamId` and `position`. This way, you can determine the position by both member and team key and get your position.

[image]